# Animation using query and Angular js

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on Hybrid iPad application using Angualr js and Phonegap. I am struck with one issues Animations.

I want animate one div from left to right and Toggle.

Default the Div should be hide.

Can any one please help me and suggest the Best way to do this Solution.

Thanks

Comment: You should provide some markup and/or what you've tried. Don't just beg for a complete code without doing some work yourself first.

Comment: Hi @Chrillewoodz, Thank you so much for Good comments. I am done something but My idea may be wrong, and i don't want code, I need idea. Thank You once Agin

Comment: if u want idea, then get an idea that we are not here to do ur homework, if u wanna do RND, google it

Comment: dont put anything just read before you ask anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add class with angular conditional expressions and make a css file having animated part.

Toggle the class value and you will get waht u need.

Or use [ng-animate](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/move).